# Why @Transactional not working in my code?

Tags: java, database, spring, exception, transactional

```
@Service
public class SingleCityService implements ICityService {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SingleCityService.class);

@Autowired
CityMmtRepo cityMmtRepo;

@Autowired
MmtCityService mmtCityService;

@Autowired
RestCityService restCityService;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    CityServiceFactory.getInstance().registor(EnumCity.SINGLE_CITY, this);
}

/**
 * Method to validate if action type is to Create city or Update city
 * 
 * @param request
 * @return CityServiceResponse
 */
@Override
public CityServiceResponse serveRequest(CityServiceRequest request) throws ResourceException, InvalidCityCreateException, SQLException {

    ValidatorFactory.getInstance().getRequestValidator(Validator.SINGLE_CITY_VALIDATOR).validate(request);

    if (CityActionType.CREATE.toString().equals(request.getEventType().getActionType())) {
        return createCity(request);
    }
    return updateCity(request);
}

/**
 * Method to create city and fetch matched cities from cache.
 * 
 * @param request
 * @return CityServiceResponse
 * @throws ResourceException
 */
private CityServiceResponse createCity(CityServiceRequest request) throws ResourceException {
    logger.info("Inside SingleCityService: Starting createCity for request: {}", request.toString());

    /**
     * forceUpdate signifies if user still want to create city after getting conflicts.
     */
    if (ResourceConstants.TRUE.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getCityDetails().get(0).getForceUpdate())) {
        return saveCity(request, ResourceConstants.CREATED);
    }

    CityCacheServiceResponse cityCacheServiceResponse = restCityService.getCityMatchingFromCityCache(request);
    CityServiceResponse cityServiceResponse = new CityServiceResponse();
    if (ResourceConstants.FAILURE.equalsIgnoreCase(cityCacheServiceResponse.getStatus())) {
        cityServiceResponse.setStatus(ResourceConstants.FAILURE);
        cityServiceResponse.setDescription(cityCacheServiceResponse.getDescription());
    } else {
        if (cityCacheServiceResponse.getCity().get(0).getMatchedCity().isEmpty()) {
            return saveCity(request, ResourceConstants.SUCCESS);
        } else {
            cityServiceResponse.setStatus(ResourceConstants.CONFLICTING_CITIES_UI_DISPLAY_MSG);
            cityServiceResponse.setCity(CityServiceMapperUtil.cacheResponse(cityCacheServiceResponse));
        }
    }
    return cityServiceResponse;
}

/**
 * To update city.
 * 
 * @param request
 * @return CityServiceResponse
 * @throws ResourceException
 */
private CityServiceResponse updateCity(CityServiceRequest request) throws ResourceException, InvalidCityCreateException {
    logger.info("Inside SingleCityService, Starting updateCity for request: {}", request.toString());
    CityMmtEntity cityMmtEntity = mmtCityService.fetchCityToEdit(request.getCityDetails().get(0).getCityCd());
    request = CityServiceMapperUtil.mapCityToBeUpdated(cityMmtEntity, request);
    return saveCity(request, ResourceConstants.UPDATE);
}

/**
 * To create or update city in DB and Push city in Cache.
 * 
 * @param request
 * @param status
 * @return CityServiceResponse
 * @throws ResourceException
 */
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public CityServiceResponse saveCity(CityServiceRequest request, String status) throws ResourceException {
    CityMmtEntity cityMmtEntity = CityServiceMapperUtil.getCityEntity(request);
    logger.info("Inside SingleCityService: saveCity: Saving city data in DB for cityCode: {}", cityMmtEntity.getChtCitycd());
    cityMmtEntity = mmtCityService.SaveToDb(cityMmtEntity);
    int i = 1/0;
    int k = i;
    logger.info("Inside SingleCityService: saveCity: Syncing city to ES API for cityCode: {}", cityMmtEntity.getChtCitycd());
    request.getCityDetails().get(0).setCityCd(cityMmtEntity.getChtCitycd());
    request.getCityDetails().get(0).setLastUpdatedOn(cityMmtEntity.getChtCityLastUpdDt());
    SyncCityCacheRequest syncCityCacheRequest = CityServiceMapperUtil.mapCityCacheRequest(request);
    SyncCityCacheResponse syncCityCacheResponse = restCityService.syncCityToCityCache(syncCityCacheRequest);
    CityServiceResponse cityServiceResponse = new CityServiceResponse();
    cityServiceResponse.setStatus(status);
    cityServiceResponse.setDescription(syncCityCacheResponse.getSyncCityDetails().get(0).getDescription());
    return cityServiceResponse;
}

}
```

// I have a method saveCity in my service class as you can see on which I have put @transactional, but it's not working, Database does not roll back on Exception.
// saveToDb is method in another service(below) which is built on Jpa Repository

```
@Service
public class MmtCityServiceImpl implements MmtCityService {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MmtCityServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private CityMmtRepo cityMmtRepo;

/**
 * To save city in DB
 * 
 * @param cityMmtEntity
 * @return {@link CityMmtEntity}
 */
public CityMmtEntity SaveToDb(CityMmtEntity cityMmtEntity) throws ResourceException {
    try {
        logger.info("Inside MmtCityServiceImpl: Starting SaveToDb to save city for CityMmtEntity: {}", cityMmtEntity.toString());
        return cityMmtRepo.save(cityMmtEntity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("MmtCityServiceImpl : Exception while saving/updating city in database, Exception: {}", e);
        throw new ResourceException(ResourceErrors.SAVE_CITY_ERROR.getErrorCode(), ResourceErrors.SAVE_CITY_ERROR.getErrorDescription());
    }
}
```

//I put k = 1/0 to throw runtime exception just next to the step where we are saving entity to db just to check if @Transactional working or not, but on exception entity does not roll back from database.
//Actually I am throwing exception from another service (whose method is SyncCityToCache) service is:-

```
@Service
public class RestCityServiceImpl implements RestCityService {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestCityService.class);

@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Value("${rest.elatic-cache-sync.end.point}")
private String cacheSyncEndPoint;

@Value("${rest.elatic-search-cache.end.point}")
private String cacheSearchEndPoint;

@Value("${rest.elatic-cache.end.point}")
private String cacheEndPoint;

public SyncCityCacheResponse syncCityToCityCache(SyncCityCacheRequest syncCityCacheRequest) throws ResourceException {
    SyncCityCacheResponse syncCityCacheResponse = null;
    try {
        logger.info("RestCityService: Hitting CityCacheServiceAPI to push city for request: {}", syncCityCacheRequest.toString());
        syncCityCacheResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(new URI(cacheSyncEndPoint), syncCityCacheRequest.getSyncCityDetails(), SyncCityCacheResponse.class);
        if (ResourceConstants.FAILURE.equalsIgnoreCase(syncCityCacheResponse.getStatus())) {
            throw new ResourceException(ResourceErrors.SYNC_API_ERROR.getErrorCode(),
                    ResourceErrors.SYNC_API_ERROR.getErrorDescription() + " " + syncCityCacheResponse.getSyncCityDetails().get(0).getDescription());
        }
    } catch (RestClientException | URISyntaxException e) {
        logger.error("RestCityService : Exception while hitting cache to push city, Exception:{}", e);
        throw new ResourceException(ResourceErrors.SYNC_API_ERROR.getErrorCode(),
                ResourceErrors.SYNC_API_ERROR.getErrorDescription() + " " + syncCityCacheResponse.getSyncCityDetails().get(0).getDescription());
    }
    return syncCityCacheResponse;
}
```

Comment: i hope you are creating ArithmeticException and in method Signature you are throwing ResourceException. you can use try(with resources) and in catch  block throw the Exception for Rollback

Comment: @Transactional(rollbackFor= Exception.class)
 public CityServiceResponse saveCity(CityServiceRequest request, String status){
  try {
   // your logic 
    int i = 1/0;
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
   throw new Exception("Exception occured while saving ");
  }
  
 }

Comment: @sgewraks, is this a SpringBoot project or just Spring MVC project?

Comment: @SpringBootApplication is mentioned on ApplicationStartup.java file.

Comment: @KathirvelSubramanian    tried that too....., I doubt if some problem in configuration......or of place where I should mention Transactional.....

Comment: Spring AOP works with proxies. Only method calls going INTO the object pass through the proxy. You are doing internal method calls basically rendering `@Transactional` useless. Make your outermost method `@Transactional` as that is your unit of work not a part of your method invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses AOP to apply transactionality to a method annotated with `@Transactional`. Spring, [by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-proxies), uses proxies to add behavior to existing classes. Generally that isn't an issue but one of the things with proxies is that only external methods calls pass through the proxy, method calls from within the object don't pass through the proxy. (See also [understanding AOP proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)).

Now as you are calling your `@Transactional` method from inside the same object it will not pass through the proxy and as such ignores the `@Transactional`. To fix your top-level method should be `@Transactional` (the `serveRequest` method).

That method is also your unit-of-work you want either to complete in full or fail in full. So the simple solution is to annotate your `serveRequest` method.

Comment: I have added @Transactional at serveRequest method and above saveToDb method also in MmtCityServiceImpl service as you advised but still not working.

Comment: Your outermost method should be transactional. Else it simply will not work (especially internal method calls).

Comment: Also make sure you have `@EnableTransactionManagement` or `<tx:annotation-driven />` to your configuration.

Comment: After adding @EnableTransactionManagement on my ApplicationStartup.java file. Bean can not be created of this file in which we are using Transactional